# (C++) No instance of constructor ... matches the argument list

Tags: c++, object, parameters, constructor

Just began learning C++ and i'm working on an assignment to display colored symbols and text in the console. For this I am creating a pen object, however I am getting an error of 'No instance of constructor matches the argument list' however I believe I am passing the correct parameters.

I've been scratching my head and stressing about this for over 2 hours now, I am hoping that someone could pick up where I have gone wrong and point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

**Main method:**

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "tui.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace textUserInterface;

int main()
{

cout << "Testing..." << endl;

byte testColor = color::red;
pen myPen(color::red, color::black, "@", true); //Error on this construction

return 0;
}
```

**Tui header file:**

```
#ifndef TUI_H
#define TUI_H

typedef unsigned char byte;

namespace textUserInterface {

class tui
{
public:
    tui();
protected:
private:
};

class color
{
public:
    static const byte magenta = 5;
    static const byte yellow = 3;
    static const byte red = 1;
    static const byte white = 7;
    static const byte green = 2;
    static const byte blue = 4;
    static const byte black = 0;
    static const byte system_default = 0;
private:
    color();
};

class pen
{
public:
    pen(byte _foreground, byte _background, char _character, bool _isBright);
private:
    byte foreground;
    byte background;
    char character;
    bool isBright;
};
}
#endif
```

**Tui cpp file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tui.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace textUserInterface;

tui::tui()
{

}

pen::pen(byte _foreground, byte _background, char _character, bool _isBright)
: foreground(_foreground), background(_background), character(_character), isBright(_isBright)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the constructor takes a `char` but you are passing a C-style string `"@"`.  You need to use single-quotes to get a single `char`, i.e. `'@'`.

If you have a good compiler, it should have given you an error message along the lines of "Cannot convert from const char* to char in argument 3."

Comment: @user3650602: You're very welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, you can mark it as "accepted" by ticking the checkmark on the left when you are able.

Answer (score 2):

```
pen myPen(color::red, color::black, "@", true);
```

`"@"` is a `const char[2]` which you try to pass in as a `char` argument.

You probably meant `'@'`:

```
pen myPen(color::red, color::black, '@', true);
```